# How to find point on a line with the closest distance?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $L$ be the line passing through the point $P=(1, 3, 3)$ with direction vector $\overrightarrow{d}=\langle{−3, −2, 0\rangle}T$. Find the shortest distance $d$ from the point $P_0= (−5, 1, 1)$ to $L$, and the point $Q$ on $L$ that is closest to $P_0$.

Sorry for the word salad title, but this question is pissing me off! I can find $D$ consistently, but I keep getting the point wrong. I was doing this question by finding the vector between $P$ and $Q$, but that isn't getting me anywhere. What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

Basically:

(1.) I found the vector of $\overrightarrow{P_0 P} = \langle{-4,9,2\rangle}$.

(2.) The vector $\overrightarrow{P_0 Q}$ was the projection of the distance vector along $\overrightarrow{P_0 P}$, which was $\langle{-15/11, -5/11,5/11\rangle}$.

(3.) I found $Q$ (The point I'm trying to look for) with $\overrightarrow{P_0 Q} + \overrightarrow{P_0}$, which was $\langle{-26/11,-60/11,-6/11\rangle}$. Then I found $\overrightarrow{QP}$ (The distance from P to Q) by $\overrightarrow{P_0 P}-\overrightarrow{P_0 Q}$ which was $d = \langle{-29/11, 109/11, 17/11\rangle}$. The distance was $9.93616.$

Comment: Can you share the details on how you found $D$?

Comment: Basically: 1. I found the vector of PoP = -4,9,2. 2. the vector of PoQ was the projection of the distance vector along PoP, which was -15/11, -5/11,5/11. 3. I found Q (The point i'm trying to look for) with PoQ + Po, which was -26/11,-60/11,-6/11. Then I found the vector of QP (The distance from P to Q) by PoP-PoQ. which was d = -29/11, 109/11, 17/11. The distance was 9.93616.

Comment: Your vector $ \ \overrightarrow{P_0P} \ $ is incorrect: that could cause a problem right away... (How are you getting 4 for the first component and 9 for the second? And you can edit your post to include your comment on how you worked out the problem.)

Comment: I'm currently working on a solution. I was generous to fix your notations, but in the future, please make sure to learn Mathjax if you want to ask interesting questions here. (It is definitely worth it.)

Comment: Assuming this is online homework, I believe I have found the point $Q$. Can you input the point $(-\frac{53}{13},-\frac{5}{13},3)$?

Answer (score 1):

We can rewrite $\overrightarrow{Q}$ as $\overrightarrow{P} + \overrightarrow{d}$. Equivalently,

$$\langle{x,y,z\rangle} = \langle{1,3,3\rangle} + T\cdot\langle{-3,-2,0\rangle} = \langle{1-3T, 3-2T, 3\rangle}.$$

Next, we will construct a vector perpendicular to $\overrightarrow{PQ_0}$ and call it $\overrightarrow{QP}$. They are

$$\overrightarrow{PQ_0} = \langle{x+5, y-1, z-1\rangle}$$
$$\overrightarrow{PQ} = \langle{x-1, y-3, z-3\rangle}.$$

Since $\|\overrightarrow{PQ_0}\|$ is the minimum distance, we will take the dot product of the vectors above which equals $0$ because they are perpendicular:

$$
\eqalign{
0 &= \overrightarrow{PQ_0} \cdot \overrightarrow{PQ} \cr
&= \langle{x+5, y-1, z-1\rangle} \cdot \langle{x-1, y-3, z-3\rangle} \cr
&= (x+5)(x+1) + (y-1)(y-3) + (z-1)(z-3).
}
$$
Replacing $x,y,z$ with the components of $\overrightarrow{Q}$ respectively, we solve for $T$ and get

$$0 = \left(\left(1-3T\right)+5\right)\left(\left(1-3T\right)-1\right)+\left(\left(3-2T\right)-1\right)\left(\left(3-2T\right)-3\right)+\left(3-1\right)\left(3-3\right).$$

Doing some algebra, we find the set of solutions $T \in \left\{\dfrac{22}{13},0\right\}$. But $\overrightarrow{Q} \neq \overrightarrow{P}$, so $t \neq 0$. Hence,

$$\overrightarrow{Q} = \bigg\langle{1-3\left(\frac{22}{13}\right),3-2\left(\frac{22}{13}\right),3\bigg\rangle} = \bigg\langle{-\frac{53}{13},-\frac{5}{13},3\bigg\rangle},$$

implying that $Q = \left(-\dfrac{53}{13},-\dfrac{5}{13},3\right)$.

Evaluating the modulus of $\overrightarrow{PQ_0}$ using the components of $\overrightarrow{Q}$, we get

$$
\eqalign{
\|\overrightarrow{PQ_0}\| &= \sqrt{\left(x+5\right)^{2}+\left(y-1\right)^{2}+\left(z-1\right)^{2}} \cr
&= \sqrt{\left(-\frac{53}{13}+5\right)^{2}+\left(-\frac{5}{13}-1\right)^{2}+\left(3-1\right)^{2}} \cr
&= \frac{2\sqrt{22}}{\sqrt{13}}.
}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Using vectors: Visualise the solution with simple co-ordinates first. Its easy if the line is in the x direction, and your point Po in the x-y plane. Its just the projection of the point Po onto the x axis that gives Q with the shortest distance.
If you follow this idea im sure you can do it.

Using Calculus: create the distance function from a paramatrization of L wrt to variable t to the point Q.
Differentiate this and solve for its zero to find t hence Po